# Magento Blurry Pictures in the Recently viewed products

Tags: image, magento, product, blurry, resize-image

I have an issue with **Magento**. My **pictures** work well in every sections but **in the **recently viewed products** I get a **blurry** result. I don't understand why because in the catalog I have the same pictures using the **"small_image"** that display fine without being blurry. I guess the reason is because the picture is **resized** to be small then resized again to be bigger, PLEASE how can I fix that.

I attached a screenshot showing the resize and how blury the pictures are.

THANKS in advance for your help !!

[Picture : Blurry Image and resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8i6D.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issues where the image is either blurry or suffered from color loss. After digging in, i found out that Magento uses the GD library out of the box which works pretty well, but there are alternatives out there. The library that solved my problems was ImageMagick. It does require you do install a php extension though and some code changes, but the results are worth it.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can you please give me more details on which php extension I should install and what changes I should make.

Comment: Sure, you would need to install the ImageMagick extension, which can be found here: http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick.

Once installed, you can override /lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/ classes to use ImageMagick vs. GD.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the quality to 100% under `Configuration/Advanced/System/Images Upload Configuration`? You need to clean the `Catalogue image cache after`.